# Cambiar de pagina sin actualizar

Tags: javascript, datatables

Tengo un DataTable cargado de registros desde un archivo Excel, tengo un buttom “Siguiente” para ir a otra pagina y otro Buttom “Volver” para regresar a la pagina inicial donde esta el DataTable. El problema que tengo es cuando hago clik en el buttom “Siguiente” para ir a otra pagina y al volver al hacer clik en el Buttom “Volver” los registros del DataTable se borran, tengo la impresión que es porque se vuelve a cargar la página. Necesito que al pasar de paginas los registros de DataTable permanezcan.
Estos son los códigos de los Buttom que estoy trabajando
En datatable.html

```
<script>

       document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
   //* const dataTable = $('#example').DataTable(dataTableOptions);

    // Al hacer clic en el botón "Análisis"
    document.getElementById('analysisButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
        // Capturar página actual
       const currentPage = dataTable.page();

        // Guardar la página actual en el almacenamiento de sesión
       sessionStorage.setItem('currentPage', currentPage);

        // Redirigir a la página de análisis
        
        window.location.href = 'Siguiente.html';
        
    });

});

  </script>
```

En HTML de la otra pagina

```
 <script>
 
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    // Al cargar la página de análisis
   const savedPage = sessionStorage.getItem('currentPage');
    if (savedPage != undefined) {
        const dataTable = $('#example').DataTable(dataTableOptions);
        dataTable.page(savedPage).draw('page');
        sessionStorage.removeItem('currentPage');
    }

    // Al hacer clic en el botón "Volver"
    document.getElementById('backButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
        // Regresar a la página anterior
        window.history.back();
    });

});

    </script>
```

Para probar la aplicación hay que tener un archivo Excel de 3 columnas con los siguientes encabezados. Los encabezados deben tener el nombre exacto como se menciona a continuación.
Cuenta
Fecha
Clase de documento

Este es el caso de prueba.  https://jsfiddle.net/JuanAlberto/10dL23q4/2/